# r: how to remove row numbers coming from a separate list in multiple data frames using lapply

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have many data frames organized in a list object. And I have a second list of vectors, that contain row numbers that I want to remove in my data frames. The rows to be removed are different for each data frame. Therefore the number of elements in the list of data frames is equal to the number of elements in the list of vectors. Here the code I've tried out:

```
test_list<-vector(mode="list",5)
test_list<-lapply(test_list, function(x) data.frame(1,1:10,"c"))
vec_list<-vector(mode="list",5)
vec_list<-lapply(vec_list, function (x) x<-sample(seq(1,10),4))
clean_list<-lapply(test_list, function (x,y) clean_list<-x[-y,],vec_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `lapply`, one way is:

```
  lapply(seq_along(test_list), function(i) test_list[[i]][-vec_list[[i]],])
```

#### Benchmarks

On a medium list data,

```
 set.seed(45)
 test_list<-vector(mode="list",25e3)
 test_list<-lapply(test_list, function(x) data.frame(1,1:10,"c"))
 vec_list<-vector(mode="list",25e3)
 vec_list<-lapply(vec_list, function (x) x<-sample(seq(1,10),4))

 library(microbenchmark)
 f1 <- function() lapply(seq_along(test_list), function(i) test_list[[i]][-vec_list[[i]],])
 f2 <- function() Map(function(l, v) l[-v,], test_list, vec_list)

 microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), unit="relative", times=25L)
 #Unit: relative
 #expr       min        lq  median       uq       max neval
 #f1() 0.9874164 0.9977816 1.00573 1.000419 0.9837334    25
 #f2() 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000 1.000000 1.0000000    25
```

Comment: Great, both solutions work perfectly. The microbenchmark seems to be a very helpfull way of evaluating the efficiency of functions. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `Map` or `mapply` functions are more natural to use than `lapply` when you have multiple lists of corresponding objects.

```
Map(function(l, v) l[-v,], test_list, vec_list)
```